# Which king of Burgundy sheltered two Robertians?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, france

I am having trouble retrieving this information. A duke or king of Burgundy took custody of, I'm pretty sure, Odo and Robert, sons of Robert the Strong. It's possible that it was some later Robertians, but I remember it being two sons. Which King of Burgundy was this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was [Hugh the Abbot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_the_Abbot) who became the regent and guardian for Robert's sons, Odo and Robert, after Robert the Strong was killed at the [Battle of Brissarthe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Brissarthe) in 866.

Robert the Strong had been defending Francia against a joint Breton-Viking raiding party. At some point during the battle, he had removed his armour. At that point, the Vikings launched a surprise attack and Robert was killed in the course of the resulting melee.

As an adult, Odo (or *Eudes*) would become King of Francia from 888 to 898.

Comment: I confused him as king of upper Burgundy because he was an Elder Welf. In actuality though, he wasn't even a Burgundian Welf, but a Bavarian one. But... the Burgundy branch at that point was Count of Auxerre, where Hugh's abbey was, I wonder if there was any familial connection?

Comment: Or if they had a relationship, I mean. @semipaiscuba

Comment: @JohnDee Hugh was the son of Conrad I of Auxerre (who was Count of Auxerre from 859–864) and Adelaide of Tours. Adelaide married Robert the Strong after Conrad's death.